# initialize GMM using sklearn python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wish to create a sklearn GMM object with a predefined set of means, weights, and covariances ( on a grid ).

I managed to do it:

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import numpy as np


def get_grid_gmm(subdivisions=[10,10,10], variance=0.05 ):
    n_gaussians = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y,subdivisions)
    step = [ 1.0/(2*subdivisions[0]),  1.0/(2*subdivisions[1]),  1.0/(2*subdivisions[2])]

    means = np.mgrid[ step[0] : 1.0-step[0]: complex(0,subdivisions[0]),
                      step[1] : 1.0-step[1]: complex(0,subdivisions[1]),
                      step[2] : 1.0-step[2]: complex(0,subdivisions[2])]
    means = np.reshape(means,[-1,3])
    covariances = variance*np.ones_like(means)
    weights = (1.0/n_gaussians)*np.ones(n_gaussians)
    gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n_gaussians, covariance_type='spherical' )
    gmm.weights_ = weights
    gmm.covariances_ = covariances
    gmm.means_ = means
    return gmm

def main():
    xx = np.random.rand(100,3)
    gmm = get_grid_gmm()
    y= gmm.predict_proba(xx)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is its missing the `gmm.predict_proba()` method that I need to use later on. 
How can I overcome this?

**UPDATE** : I updated the code to be a complete example that shows the error

**UPDATE2**

I updated the code according to comments and answers

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import numpy as np


def get_grid_gmm(subdivisions=[10,10,10], variance=0.05 ):
    n_gaussians = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y,subdivisions)
    step = [ 1.0/(2*subdivisions[0]),  1.0/(2*subdivisions[1]),  1.0/(2*subdivisions[2])]

    means = np.mgrid[ step[0] : 1.0-step[0]: complex(0,subdivisions[0]),
                      step[1] : 1.0-step[1]: complex(0,subdivisions[1]),
                      step[2] : 1.0-step[2]: complex(0,subdivisions[2])]
    means = np.reshape(means,[3,-1])
    covariances = variance*np.ones(n_gaussians)
    cov_type = 'spherical'
    weights = (1.0/n_gaussians)*np.ones(n_gaussians)
    gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n_gaussians, covariance_type=cov_type )
    gmm.weights_ = weights
    gmm.covariances_ = covariances
    gmm.means_ = means
    from sklearn.mixture.gaussian_mixture import _compute_precision_cholesky
    gmm.precisions_cholesky_ = _compute_precision_cholesky(covariances, cov_type)
    gmm.precisions_ = gmm.precisions_cholesky_ ** 2
    return gmm

def main():
    xx = np.random.rand(100,3)
    gmm = get_grid_gmm()
    _, y = gmm._estimate_log_prob(xx)
    y = np.exp(y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

No more errors but _estimate_log_prob and predict_proba do not produce the same result for a fitted GMM. Why could that be?

Comment: You never return the gmm object.

Comment: oops ! thanks, got lost in the ctrl+c ctrl+v. but this is not the cause of the poblem

Comment: Another problem that you have, is that your means should have two dimensions (nb components, n_features). Here you have tensors, sklearn doesn't allow that.

Comment: @Anis thanks. fixed it too. but this is still not the problem. The thing is that I am not running `gmm.fit()`. so the gmm is not fully defined. how can I make it defined ?

Comment: ```from sklearn.mixture.gaussian_mixture import _compute_precision_cholesky
``` then ```gmm.precisions_cholesky_ = _compute_precision_cholesky(covariances, cov_type)``` but then you'll stumble on what I said. Your shape for the means will cause the "Too many values to unpack" error

Comment: @Anis I fixed according to your comments. However I get the following error
`sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py", line 430, in _estimate_log_gaussian_prob
    2 * np.dot(X, means.T * precisions) +
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (1000,) ` I updated the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't train the model but just use the function for estimation, you don't need to use the object but you could use the same function they use under the hood. You could try `_estimate_log_gaussian_prob`. That is what they do internaly I think.

Have a look at the source:

in particular at the base class
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d657eb4268ac20c4db01c48065b5a1bfe80d/sklearn/mixture/base.py#L342

that is calling the specific method, that in turn is calling a function
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d657eb4268ac20c4db01c48065b5a1bfe80d/sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py#L671

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did what you said but I get this error `sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py", line 430, in _estimate_log_gaussian_prob
    2 * np.dot(X, means.T * precisions) +
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (1000,) ` any idea whats wrong? I updated the code above

Comment: So I found the dimension problem and fixed, updated the code) it but now the result of `_estimate_log_prob` and `predict_proba` are not the same (for a fitted model).... why could that be?  @Anis, @Gioelelm

Comment: yes you need to adjust for the weights, that's also in the source I linked

Comment: can you be a little more specific ?

Comment: ok. I solved it. once I added `    from sklearn.mixture.gaussian_mixture import _compute_precision_cholesky
    gmm.precisions_cholesky_ = _compute_precision_cholesky(covariances, cov_type)` I could simply use `predict_proba()`directly and it eorks fine. thanks.

Comment: @Gioelelm hi, I was wondering if you could have a look at a similar problem in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414169/how-can-implement-em-gmm-in-python)
Thanks in advance.